# how to get a URL parameter with regexp/javascript-method in a URL with hash-elements?

Tags: javascript, url, parameters, hashtag

I'm trying to extract a string from an url. The URL can either be:

```
http://page.de/s/project.html?id=1
```

or

```
http://page.de/s/project.html?id=1/#/s/project.html?id=x
```

I need to extract the last `?id=-value` but I can't get it to go. This is what I have:

```
url_snip = key.replace("?id=","")
```

which only works for the first URL.

**Question:**
Is there a `regexp` or method to get the last id value no matter whats the URL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can extract using `split` on `location.search`

```
var ids = window.location.search.split('&')[0].split('=');
ids[0] //id;
 ids[1] //1
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the two forms you posted:

```
url_snip = key.substring(key.lastIndexOf('=') + 1);
```

[JS Fiddle demo (admittedly using a function, but it's the same approach)](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2a25h/).

And an alternative, using `split()`:

```
var parts = url.split('=');
    return parts[parts.length - 1];
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2a25h/2/).

Comment: @jbabey: [you're wrong](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2a25h/1/). Without a second argument `substring()` will return the substring starting at the index passed by the *first* argument, until the end of the string.